# How to use Nokia Qt to launch another mobile application within an application based upon a MIME type?

Tags: qt, mobile, mime-types, qt-creator, nokia

I am using Qt Nokia for mobile development (I'm currently testing on a Nokia C7) and would like to launch an application from another an application based upon a MIME type.

For example, I might have a file, and I would like to be able to open another application from the original application without specifying the application but using the MIME type of that file. On the other application opening it would load the file and perhaps be given an additional message or payload.

If this sounds a little strange it might help to know that I have come from a [J2ME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition) background and would have used the [CHAPI API](http://mobilezoo.biz/jsr/211/index.html).

I need to use Qt Nokia so that I can build the application for the [Symbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbian) or [Maemo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maemo) platform. So far I have only been able to find documentation showing you how to [do it under Symbian](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Launching_default_application_based_on_MIME_type).

Can I do what I require by using Qt Nokia? I am just not looking the right places?

Answer (score 0):

[QDesktop::openUrl](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) may be a good candidate.

This [HowTo](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_launch_other_applications_in_Qt) may be helpful.

Comment: Although I did consider this I did not see a way to launch the other application based on mime-type alone.